# Remove next element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove next element using jquery here is my code please check it.

```
  <span id="t1">Test 1</span><br/>
  <span id="t2">Test 2</span><br/> // I want to remove this <br/>
  <span id="t3">Test 3</span><br/>
```

Here is a jquery code but this is not working.

```
   $('#t2').next().remove();
```

I want to remove `<br/>` which is after the `t2`.

Comment: $('br').next('br').remove(); 
use this code

Comment: Your code should work as written. What problem are you having?

Comment: Your format of `comment` in html is incorrect. The `<br/>` of your comment is forcing the third `span` to go to next line. For reference you can see my answer below.

Comment: Your code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/fftek2rf/

Comment: There is no problem with your code, It seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").on("click",function(){

        $("#t2").next().remove("br");

    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    
    
    <span id="t1">Test 1</span><br/>
    <span id="t2">Test 2</span> <!--I want to remove this--><br>
    <span id="t3">Test 3</span>
    <br><br>
    <button>Remove</button>
    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("button").on("click",function(){

            $("#t2").next().remove("br");

        })
    })
    </script>
     
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#t2").next("br").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="t1">Test 1</span><br/>
<span id="t2">Test 2</span><br/> 
<span id="t3">Test 3</span><br/>
```

This might help you.

Your jquery code is working fine but the main problem was your `comment` in the html code

```
// I want to remove this <br/>
```

It should be

```
<!-- I want to remove this <br/> -->
```

Comment: Why does this work differently? `.next()` without an argument just finds the next element without checking whether it's a `br`, but it should still find it.

Comment: Do you really think he has that comment in his real HTML? I think it's just for the question.

Comment: @Barmar hopefully that comment was added for the question, but without that comment `.next()` works as expected. so i'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

using [nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) method allows us to search through the successors of these elements in the DOM tree

if one ahead br element

```
$('#t2').next('br').remove();
```

if not

```
$('#t2').nextAll('br').remove();
```

Comment: Why? There's only one `<br>`.

Comment: when you work for one or more br, it may be the case, it may be a more comprehensive solution

Comment: `.nextAll("br").first()` is the same as `.next("br")`. Why call 2 functions when one function will do the same thing?

Comment: My view is we should find out what he's really doing, and what the problem is, before we waste any more time answering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your jQuery code to some sort of event, like
https://jsfiddle.net/ps2aoey7/

Also, in this case you don't need the next() function.

HTML

```
  <span id="t1">Test 1</span><br/>
  <span id="t2">Test 2<br/> // I want to remove this <br/></span>
  <span id="t3">Test 3</span><br/>
```

jQuery option 1 (click event)

```
$( "#t2" ).click(function() {
  $('#t2').remove();
});
```

jQuery option 2 (on page load)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#t2').remove();
});
```

Comment: Why does he need to bind it to a click event? What if he wants to do it when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code is working. Because there is nothing wrong in the code. It should work.

Maybe your CSS is the actual problem.

If your css is set to display `<span>` in the next line (display block or anything else) it will not show code's effect. Though it's just an assumption but it's better to check that out.

And as @Dev and @Sidharth said it's better to keep a selector in the next().